# Why there is a shadow between nested navigator?

Tags: flutter

When i use navigator nested in MaterialApp that contains a navigator, there is shadow as showed in the following image.

Why? How to remove this shadow?

[image]

My code is here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(NavigatorNested());

class NavigatorNested extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    NavigatorNestedState createState() => NavigatorNestedState();
}

class NavigatorNestedState extends State<NavigatorNested> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            initialRoute: 'hpme',
            title: 'test',
            theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text('helle world'),
                ),
                body: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 48, horizontal: 24),
                        child: Navigator(
                        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                            return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
                                settings: settings,
                                builder: (context) {
                                return Text('helle world');
                            });
                        },
                        onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
                            return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
                                settings: settings,
                                builder: (context) {
                                return Text('helle world');
                            });
                        },
                        initialRoute: "home",
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

If i use `Text('hello')` to replace `Navigator`, it works goods. Is it a bug in flutrer?

Answer (score 12):

`MaterialPageRoute` is not a Material Widget itself. This shadow only occurs on iOS and is coming from the `buildPageTransitions` method in `CupertinoPageRoute` class....

When using a `MaterialPageRoute` Flutter looks at your `pageTransitionsTheme` and by default on iOS returns a `CupertinoPageRouteTransitionsBuilder` and Android a `FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder`

The shadow is part of iOS' default page transition but there might be good reasons why one doesn't want these to show up.

See:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PageTransitionsTheme-class.html
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/flutter/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart

There are a couple of solutions:

---

(1) Using a custom `PageRouteBuilder` (and building your own transitions) as suggested earlier works but it will break the default "swipe back" gesture on iOS that is implemented in `CupertinoPageRoute`.

(2) Define `FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder` as the default transition on iOS also. But again this will break the swipe back gesture on iOS.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
      builders: {
        TargetPlatform.iOS: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
        TargetPlatform.android: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
      }
    ),
  ),
  ...
)
```

(3) Subclass `CupertinoPageTransition` and override `build`. Inside the build function there is an animation `_primaryShadowAnimation` that you don't need. This will keep the swipe back gesture on iOS intact. You would also have to subclass some parent classes such as `CupertinoPageRouteTransitionsBuilder` to return your custom `CupertinoPageTransition` instead
So instead of:

```
# file: packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart, lines: 407-410
child: DecoratedBoxTransition(
  decoration: _primaryShadowAnimation,
  child: child,
),
```

you return child directly:

```
child: child,
```

Comment: I fought the dragon: https://gist.github.com/alhafoudh/ce139a745c39efccc6e5fb6b4b1b399b

Comment: if you're working on web and dont care about iOS, option 2 works nicely

Comment: @AhmedAlHafoudh i dont understand this gist.github.com/alhafoudh/ce139a745c39efccc6e5fb6b4b1b399b i am also having this issue.... what i dont understand is that will class to for page translate ?

Answer (score 12):

You could wrap your navigator in a ClipRect.

`return ClipRect(child:Navigator(`

Answer (score 7):

The MaterialPageRoute itself is a material widget, so it has an elevation and a shadow.

Use [PageRouteBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageRouteBuilder-class.html) instead, this is the pageroute that does not contain the material effect. A good example is in the 'Custom route' section of [Navigator](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) documentation.

Edit: sorry, it seems the example in the documentation does not fit into your scenario. You can use PageRouteBuilder like this

```
Navigator(
    //...
    onGeneratedRoute: PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => yourWidget,
        transitionsBuilder: //There are some good examples about this transition animation on the web
    ),
    //...
)
```

Answer (score -3):

I think i found a working solution to this:

Go to `flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\cupertino\route.dart`

Change this part (it should be line 789):

```
static DecorationTween kTween = DecorationTween(
    begin: const _CupertinoEdgeShadowDecoration._(), // No decoration initially.
    end: const _CupertinoEdgeShadowDecoration._(
      // Eyeballed gradient used to mimic a drop shadow on the start side only.
      <Color>[
        Color(0x38000000),
        Color(0x12000000),
        Color(0x04000000),
        Color(0x00000000),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

To this:

```
static DecorationTween kTween = DecorationTween(
    begin: const _CupertinoEdgeShadowDecoration._(), // No decoration initially.
    end: const _CupertinoEdgeShadowDecoration._(
      // Eyeballed gradient used to mimic a drop shadow on the start side only.
      <Color>[
        Color(0x00FFFFFF),
        Color(0x00FFFFFF),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

What this does is: It replaces the default shadow color to transparent.

Comment: Do NOT change the framework files, this will work on your device only and to this installed version only.

Comment: @AbdullahAlsigar while changing framework files is not preferred and should be avoided, i don't see any harm in doing small changes on a single file like this, especially when there is no other solution for the problem. Being able to change source files is literally one of the main points of open source projects.